# Android app crashes on some lower end mobiles

Tags: android

I have a simple drawing app. I have an option to open any image on gallery and draw on it. I am calling gallery intent and getting image from there. This process is working on most of the mobiles. I got complaint from few users that it crashes when they try to open an image. I am not sure why it is working on most of the mobiles and failing to do so in some. What can be the probable issue? And how to debug such issues when it is not crashing on most of the phones and I dont have the phones, where it is crashing, to test on.

There is one more scenario where it is crashing, not crashing exactly, but restarting. When I am calling a sub-activity and returning from there , it restarts on some mobiles. It keeps the data coming from sub-activity but restarts my app (My drawing is lost). What could be the probable cause of this?

Since I dont have the mobiles where it is crashing , it is very hard to test such things.

Comment: Have you tried running it on an emulator with similar specs?

Comment: If you create emulator images that match the hardware and OS versions of the phones with reported problems, can you replicate the error?

Comment: I have a couple of old devices I could try it on, if it has the same issue I might be able to see an error in logcat. What's the app?

Comment: Thanks a lot Chops. App name is scribble. Here is the link : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=scribble.pikkensn&hl=en . Please try it  on your devices and let me know If you find any crashes.

Comment: Hi Tanis and Curly, I tried it on emulator with same configs , but it didnt work. What could be the possible reason for such crashes. Un-optimized use of memory or something ?